# CSS Margin problem

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm starting out in HTML and CSS.
I have a div element on the page, which doesn't fill the whole page.
In it- there's a ul element and some list items in it.
I want to put the list 227px from the top of the div element, but I can't manage to accomplish this- it pushes it more.
Also- between the list items I want a margin of 40 pixels, but it also does more.
What's the problem?
Here's my code:
Html:

```
<body>
    <div class="Hashta">
        <div class="Menu">
            <ul id="MenuItems">
              <li><a href="#" >ONE</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" >TWO</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" >THREE</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" >FOUR</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
   background-color: Gray;
}
.Hashta{
   width:874px;
   height:650px;
   background-color:black;
   margin: auto auto 50px auto;
   border-radius: 20px;
   border: 3px solid darkgray;
   moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px black;
   webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px black;
   box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px black;
}
.Menu {
   margin-top: 227px;
   padding-right: 50px;
   float:right;
}

#MenuItems {
   list-style:none;
}
#MenuItems li {
   text-align:center;  
   position:relative;  
   padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;  
   margin-right:30px;  
   margin-bottom: 40px;  
   border:none;  
}

#MenuItems li a{
   width: 280px;
   height: 70px;
   background-color: green;
   color:White;
   font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
   font-size:24px;  
   display:block;  
   outline:0;  
   text-decoration:none;  
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
   line-height: 70px;  
}
```

If you want to measure the pixels- you can install this: http://www.mioplanet.com/products/pixelruler/
(click to rotate)
Thanks!

Comment: If you are starting out I would consider using a reset stylesheet. I always use one and it definitely helps. It strips out all the browser related styles and makes it a lot easier by giving you a "blank canvas". I always use this one http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Looks alright to me  - [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/2XBWn/)

Comment: Keep in mind though that if you use a CSS reset, you'd better replace the sensible defaults you're unsetting with others. There's default styling for a reason.

Comment: Thanks @kiz. I used Jose Faeti's method for reseting, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start your styling by resetting all elements so that each browser shows them identical.

You can check one of the many CSS reset libraries around there, but for starting something like this would be already good:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

This, appearing for first in your CSS stylesheet, will remove all margins and paddings for each element, so you can add them later only in the elements you want.

**Update**
If you want to restore some element margins or paddings after that code (for example in body) simply write a new rule after the one before, like

```
body {
  padding:10px; /* Add 10px to body only */
}
```

Comment: Using a reset stylesheet may be of good use, but it does not help OP in this case.

Comment: Reading the question, there is a div which doesn't fit the page (body padding maybe?), and also "I want to put the list 227px from the top of the div element, but I can't manage to accomplish this- it pushes it more.
 Also- between the list items I want a margin of 40 pixels, but it also does more." So I think resetting would be a great start, just to be sure.

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. Margin and padding work now like I want them to. One question: can I exclude the body element from that?

Comment: Reading the question is something completely different than studying or understanding the question.

Comment: @amitairos I don't see how just this could have helped you. The problem is your implicit padding-top and padding-bottom on the list items.

Comment: @amitairos edited with instruction on how to restore the body paddings after the reset rule. Glad I could help.

Comment: @NGLN it helped because it's good practice, and good practices should always be followed, cause they save you hours and hours of debugging and time loss.

Comment: +1 was wondering how long it'd take for someone to mention defining margin and padding as 0 with *{}

Comment: @Jose Ok, fair is fair since this now is the accepted answer. But Kiz mentioned this _"anwser"_ 11 minutes before, and like You mentioned also earlier: reset stylesheets are NOT holy. I have never had the need using them.

Comment: Like I said, resetting styles is a good practice to follow. May you need it or not, that depends on you. +1 to Kiz and sorry if I didn't notice the comment before giving my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The total height of every list item is height + padding + border + margin.

Change the padding of `#MenuItems li` into:

```
 padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/rBjrD/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try absolute positioning:

```
.Hashta{
   width:874px;
   height:650px;
   background-color:black;
   margin: auto auto 50px auto;
   border-radius: 20px;
   border: 3px solid darkgray;
   moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px black;
   webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px black;
   box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px black;
   position:relative;
}
.Menu {
       position:absolute;
       top:227px;
       right:0;
       padding-right: 50px;
       float:right;
    }
```

Comment: Total _height_ = height + padding + border + margin

Comment: You're right @NGLN but padding is within the border of an element and is not accounted for in the gap between two elements.

Comment: I changed the .Menu margin to padding, but there are still about 20px more than I want there to be.

Comment: When you work with fixed layouts like this i guess absolute positioning and layers are working best here. Try absolute positioning.

Comment: The absolute makes it float to the left

Comment: Absolute positioning is NOT desired nor required in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin:0; padding:0` for `body`

In `#MenuItems li` replace:

```
padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
```

with:

```
margin: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
```

This will make the distance equal to 40px between buttons.

Comment: It does, but not for the reason you declare. Further down the declarations is another margin-bottom that results in the desired 40px margin, not yóur margin declaration. Forthermore: this answer still gives no solution for the other part of the question, which is to set a specific margin at the top.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<style> 
body {
   background-color: Gray;
}
.Hashta{
   width:874px;
   height:650px;
   background-color:black;
   margin: auto auto 50px auto;
   border-radius: 20px;
   border: 3px solid darkgray;
   moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px black;
   webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px black;
   box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px black;
}
.Menu {
   margin-top: 227px;
   padding-right: 50px;
   float:right;
}

#MenuItems {
   list-style:none;
}
.secLi{
   text-align:center;  
   position:relative;  
   padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;  
   margin-right:30px;  
   margin-top: 40px;  
   border:none;  
}
.firstLi{
   text-align:center;  
   position:relative;  
   padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;  
   margin-right:30px;  
   margin-top: -16px;  
   border:none;  
}

#MenuItems li a{
   width: 280px;
   height: 70px;
   background-color: green;
   color:White;
   font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
   font-size:24px;  
   display:block;  
   outline:0;  
   text-decoration:none;  
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
   line-height: 70px;  
}
</style>

<body>
    <div class="Hashta">

        <div class="Menu">
            <ul id="MenuItems">
              <li class="firstLi"><a href="#" >ONE</a></li>
              <li class="secLi"><a href="#" >TWO</a></li>
              <li class="secLi"><a href="#" >THREE</a></li>
              <li class="secLi"><a href="#" >FOUR</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```